# ¿Cómo agrupar columnas de dos dataTable en vb net?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Que tal, tengo dos DataTable, uno de ellos solo tiene una columna que devuelve un id, el otro DataTable me devuelve un id, y una columna de correos, se ven los datos de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es agrupar los datos para que se vean de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y esa forma de agrupar.. tiene alguna logica??? salvo que tienen un correo repetido??? y como los cargas a los dos datatable???

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres hacer... ¿Podrías ser mas explicito?

Comment: Que tal @Crisitina Carrasco Angulo quiero tener en una sola fila los correos y los id que se relacionan, por ejemplo el id 1 tiene el correo1, correo2 y vemos que el correo 2 también lo tiene el id 2, entonces quiero como resultado en una fila lo siguiente:

1,2 correo1,correo2.

Comment: Parece que el ID 1 también tenga el correo3 y según tu tabla eso no es así. Tampoco el ID 2 tiene el correo1.